# C Undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, declaration

I am getting this weird error:

```
app_server.c: In function ‘wasFeedRead’:
app_server.c:269:14: error: ‘tmp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     readers* tmp;
              ^
app_server.c:269:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

My wasFeedRead Function is just containing this few lines:

```
int wasFeedRead(char* loginName, readers* readers){
    readers* tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Reader was defined in the following way:

```
struct readers {
    char *user;
    struct readers *next;
};
typedef struct readers readers;
```

The Error is in the `readers* tmp;` line and not in the `int wasFeedRead(char* loginName, readers* readers)` line so the declaration of readers should be right..

Im really frustrated with this error, does anyone know how to fix this? I already tried to change the Var. Name but that didnt change anything (Suprise Suprise). 

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are the headers, how are you compiling these

Comment: for your own sanity, don't use variables that have the same name as a type, even in a context where it might work.

Comment: <br>im compiling with "make -f Makefile.app" this are all my files https://www.file-upload.net/download-12791072/Lsung.tar.gz.html

Comment: github: https://github.com/masterholdy/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter name is shaddowing the type name inside the function body.
It could be resolved by renaming the type or the parameter name.

Example:

```
struct readers {
    char *user;
    struct readers *next;
};
typedef struct readers Readers;
```

here the type is Readers and then it wont collide with readers that is the name of the parameter.

```
int wasFeedRead(char* loginName, Readers* readers){
    Readers* tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not the actual problem! Problem is that parameter name is the same as typedef name!

Comment: Yes, I've seem that now... Should I delete my answear?

Comment: Absolutely not. just correct it with my comment. Current answer is a "workaround", but not the correct approach.

Answer (score 4):

The function parameter name `readers` hides the type name `readers`

```
int wasFeedRead(char* loginName, readers* readers){
    readers* tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

So within the function the name `readers` is considered as a variable. Use some else name for the parameter.

Or use the elaborated type name in the declaration

```
    struct readers* tmp;
```